# View an Account’s Storage

Tags: onflow-cadence

Is there a way to query an AuthAccount’s storage? For example, to see all of the resources stored under the /storage/... domain.

I’m fairly new to Flow, but from what I have gathered there is no real way to query or check all of the saved paths in an Account’s storage directly from within Cadence. In the Flow Playground, there is a pane that shows an accounts storage, but it seems to me like this is just being saved in the browser.

If not, is there a reason for not allowing this? Seems like it would be pretty useful to have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way to iterate over an account’s paths. This is not intentionally missing, just technically complex to implement, but it is in the works https://github.com/onflow/cadence/issues/208.